# I am trying to have a delete option in my program which deletes the record of an employee depending on the name the user inputs

Tags: python-3.x

```
lst = []

if optionpicked == "d":
        print("delete an employee record")
        employee = str(input("Enter employee name to delete: "))
        for employee in lst:
            print("Employee removed")
            lst.remove(employee)
```

Option `a` adds an employee record to my program and stores the record in a list which works fine.

Option `d` should delete the employees record by searching the name which the user inputs to the program. If I just enter 1 or 2 employees, then delete will work; however when 3 or more employees are added, the wrong employee is deleted (not the name I entered)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same name for both the employee to delete, and the current employee in the loop, and you are modifying the list while iterating over it.  All bad things.

Instead of using a loop to remove every employee, just use the `.remove()` method to remove the employee the user specified:

```
if optionpicked == 'd':
    print('delete an employee record')
    employee = input('Enter employee name to delete: ')
    lst.remove(employee)
```

You may also want to guard against the user misspelling the name (or entering a name you don't have yet).  You can do this with either an `if` test or a `try/except` guard.

The `if` test might be:

```
if optionpicked == 'd':
    print('delete an employee record')
    employee = input('Enter employee name to delete: ')
    if employee in lst:
        lst.remove(employee)
    else:
        print('%r not found' % employee)
```

and the `try/except` might look like:

```
if optionpicked == 'd':
    print('delete an employee record')
    employee = input('Enter employee name to delete: ')
    try:
        lst.remove(employee)
    except IndexError:
        print('%r not found' % employee)
```